# How to center this div between two div colums in reactjs using only css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to center the `feed` div between the left and right column for a while now and I just cant make it work. I am currently using reactjs, but I haven't taken the time to learn bootstrap yet so I am making do with some css.

Here is what my code looks like right now (I am new to react so I think the code could be cleaner) and here is an image of the page
[image: Here is an image of the page with using the css below]

```
  function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className = "navibar"> 
        <Header />
        </div>
          <div className = 'container'>
            <div className = 'feed'>
              <form className = "status">
                <label for = "user" className = "statususer">What's on your mind?</label><br></br>
                <input type="text" className = "statusbox"></input><br></br>
                <button type = "submit" value = "Submit">SUBMIT</button>
              </form>
              <div>
              <Posts data = {StatusPosts} />
              </div>
            </div> 
              <div className = "left-column">
                <div className = 'ads'>
                <hr></hr>
                data
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className = "right-column">
                <div>
                  data
                </div>
              </div> 
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My css for the formatting of the divs looks like this.

```
.left-column{
width: 20%;
float: left;
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 9, 128);
padding: 10px;
height: 100vh;
position: sticky;
}

.feed {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-column{
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 9, 128);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and using `order` property you can order the `feed`, `left-column` and `right-column` as:

[READ ABOUT ORDER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

[DEMO CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dawn-e28ry?file=/src/styles.css:0-31)

```
.container {              // Change
  display: flex;
}

.left-column {
  order: 1;              // Change
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 9, 128);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
}

.feed {
  order: 2;               // Change
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-column {
  order: 3;              // Change
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 9, 128);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want?